# rrdtool info ds unknown_sec meaning

Tags: rrdtool, info

The answer to this question is probably obvious, but I couldn't figure out what it means nor find the documentation for it. When I run `rrdtool info`, I get `ds[source].unknown_sec = 0`, and I am not sure what it exactly means...Any help or pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `unknown_sec` is the number of seconds for which the value of the DS is `Unknown`.  This could be because the supplied value was `Unknown`, or was outside the specified range, or because the time since the last sample exceeds the heartbeat time (which marks everything since then as Unknown).

The amount of Unknown time in an interval is then used in combination with the `xff` fraction in the RRA definitions to determine if a consolodated data point stored in the RRA is Unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think I figured out what it means. If two data samples exceed the heartbeat value, then the entire interval between the two data samples are marked as unknown. So unknown_sec = 0 means there hasn't been two data samples that exceed the heartbeat value.